# Xamarin app crashes after launch screen on iOS 12

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

So I made an app using Xamarin.Forms v3.4.0 tested an android device and on my iPhone (SE, iOS 13.3) and it works perfect.
Just as a test I ran it on an older device (iPhone 6, iOS 12.4) and it crashes just after the blue launch screen.

The problem is that it doesn't even starts the debugger. Crashes so early that the debugger doesn't even start yet, so I have no idea how to identify what is causing the crash. Tried putting breakpoints on Main.cs and AppDelegate.cs first line's and, again, debugger doesn't stops there.

After that I thought it may have something to do with the device's processor so I set up a simulator for an iPhone SE with iOS 12.4 (same device, older OS) and it crashes just the same. So yeah, it has to be something about the OS version.

Other of my ideas is that maybe it's something dark mode - related (I'm sorry I'm just throwing ideas). I implemented Dark mode using  [this guide](https://lalorosas.com/blog/dark-mode)

I have no idea where to begin with this, any help it's appreciated.

**Edit:**
Just updated Xamarin.Forms to 4.4.x and I still have the exact same problem.

Comment: You could better update the version of XF to the latest version (4.4.x) . Debug the app in such old version will maybe cause unkinow issue .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT well just updated and exactly the same

Comment: doesnt give much idea about the problem. Try cleaning the solution, delete bin/obj, if on vs mac delete .vs/ in project root and rebuild and try again. Seeing Console logs of the simulator from xcode also might give some idea

Comment: try enabling `common language runtime exception` n see for any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually in the custom page renderer I use to handle the Dark Mode. Apparently, the `previousTraitCollection` argument of `TraitCollectionDidChange()` is null in iOS 12.

So it was just a `NullReferenceException`very easily fixed:

```
if (previousTraitCollection == null)
    return;
```

I have no idea why the debugger didn't start in time to identify the error, but by mere luck, I discovered it by modifying the `Linker Behavior` to `Link Framework SDKs Only`